# How to use sharedpreferences to save users roles and use them to keep the user logged and naviagte to a specific page depending on role in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sharedpreferences

I'm working on a doctor consulting app and I have to user logins(The doctor Login and the Client Login).
My problem is that after closing the app and restarting if the doctor is logged in it will go to the client's homepage instead of the doctor's homepage. In my startup file I have `

```
class HomeController extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthService auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder<String>(
      stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
          return signedIn ? UsersHome() : OnboardingScreen();
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }`
I
```

I want to use shared preferences to save the user roles locally on the app. So if the Client's log in it will go to the ClientHome and if the doctor log in it will go to the DoctorHome.
Is there any alternatives. My backend is firebase

I need help
This my login page is similar to the doctor login
    enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

```
final primaryColor = Colors.blue;

enum AuthFormType { signIn, signUp, reset, anonymous, convert }
class Login extends StatefulWidget {

  final AuthFormType authFormType;

  Login({Key key, @required this.authFormType}) : super(key: key);
    @override
  _LoginState createState() =>
   _LoginState(authFormType: this.authFormType);
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
 AuthFormType authFormType;

  _LoginState({this.authFormType});
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password, _name, _warning;

  void switchFormState(String state) {
    formKey.currentState.reset();
    if (state == "signUp") {
      setState(() {
        authFormType = AuthFormType.signUp;
      });
    } else if (state == 'home') {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        authFormType = AuthFormType.signIn;
      });
    }
  }


  bool validate() {
    final form = formKey.currentState;
    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.anonymous) {
      return true;
    }
    form.save();
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void submit() async {
    if (validate()) {
      try {
        final auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
        switch (authFormType) {
          case AuthFormType.signIn:
            await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(_email, _password);

            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');

            break;
          case AuthFormType.signUp:
            await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
            (
                _email, _password, _name);
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
            break;
          case AuthFormType.reset:
            await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(_email);
            _warning = "A password reset link has been sent to $_email";
            setState(() {
              authFormType = AuthFormType.signIn;
            });
            break;
          case AuthFormType.anonymous:
            await auth.singInAnonymously();
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
            break;
          case AuthFormType.convert:
            await auth.convertUserWithEmail(_email, _password, _name);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            break;
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        setState(() {
          _warning = e.message;
        });
      }
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _auth = Provider.of(context).auth;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
       color: Color(0xFF5bd75b)
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 80,),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,  //m8Oq9ycK9VntE8mk8om5yoQbB10=   first one
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(child: FadeAnimation(1, buildHeaderText(),), ),

                  SizedBox(height: 10,),

                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         color: Color(0xFF32cd32),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(60), topRight: Radius.circular(60))
                ),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 0,),
                        FadeAnimation(1.4, Container(

                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[

                showAlert(),

                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: buildInputs(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                                         SizedBox(height: 0,),
            FadeAnimation(2,
            Container(

                    child: Column(
                      children:buildButtons(),
                    ),

            )
            ),


                        SizedBox(height: 0,),
                        FadeAnimation(1.7, Text("Continue with social media", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),

                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: FadeAnimation(1.8, Container(
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  color: Colors.blue
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text("Facebook", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                               onPressed: (){

                               },
                                )

                                ),
                              )),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 30,),
                            Expanded(
                              child: FadeAnimation(1.9, Container(
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  color: Colors.white
                                ),
                                child: Center(

                                  child: FlatButton(

                                   child: Text("Google", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),

                                               onPressed: () async {
                     try {
                   if(authFormType == AuthFormType.convert) {
                  await _auth.convertWithGoogle();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                } else {
                  await _auth.signInWithGoogle();
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/home');
                }
              } catch (e) {
                setState(() {
                  print(e);
                  _warning = e.message;
                });
              }

                                 },

                                  ) 

                                ),
                              )),
                            )

                          ],
                        ),
                         SizedBox(height: 0),
                         FadeAnimation(3, FlatButton(child:Text('By continueing, you agree to Terms & Conditions', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12, ),              ),          
                        onPressed: (){
                     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Terms');
                        },
                        )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget showAlert() {
    if (_warning != null) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                _warning,
                maxLines: 3,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _warning = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }

AutoSizeText buildHeaderText() {
    String _headerText;
    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signIn) {
      _headerText = "Sign In";
    } else if (authFormType == AuthFormType.reset) {
      _headerText = "Reset Password";
    } else {
      _headerText = "Create New Account";
    }
    return AutoSizeText(
      _headerText,
      maxLines: 1,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 35,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }


    List<Widget> buildInputs() {
    List<Widget> textFields = [];
    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.reset) {
      textFields.add(
        TextFormField(
          validator: EmailValidator.validate,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
          decoration: buildSignUpInputDecoration("Email"),
          onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
        ),
      );
      textFields.add(SizedBox(height: 20));
      return textFields;
    }

    // if were in the sign up state add name
    if ([AuthFormType.signUp, AuthFormType.convert].contains(authFormType)) {
      textFields.add(
        TextFormField(
          validator: NameValidator.validate,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
          decoration: buildSignUpInputDecoration("Full Name"),
          onSaved: (value) => _name = value,
        ),
      );
      textFields.add(SizedBox(height: 20));
    }

    // add email & password
    textFields.add(
      TextFormField(
        validator: EmailValidator.validate,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
        decoration: buildSignUpInputDecoration("Email"),
        onSaved: (value) => _email = value,
      ),
    );
    textFields.add(SizedBox(height: 20));
    textFields.add(
      TextFormField(
        validator: PasswordValidator.validate,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
        decoration: buildSignUpInputDecoration("Password"),
        obscureText: true,
        onSaved: (value) => _password = value,
      ),
    );
    textFields.add(SizedBox(height: 20));

    return textFields;
  }

  InputDecoration buildSignUpInputDecoration(String hint) {
    return InputDecoration(
      hintText: hint,
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      focusColor: Colors.white,
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 0.0)),
      contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 10.0, top: 10.0),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildButtons() {
    String _switchButtonText, _newFormState, _submitButtonText;
    bool _showForgotPassword = false;

    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signIn) {
      _switchButtonText = "Create New Account";
      _newFormState = "signUp";
      _submitButtonText = "Sign In";
      _showForgotPassword = true;
    } else if (authFormType == AuthFormType.reset) {
      _switchButtonText = "Return to Sign In";
      _newFormState = "signIn";
      _submitButtonText = "Submit";
    } else if (authFormType == AuthFormType.convert) {
      _switchButtonText = "Cancel";
      _newFormState = "home";
      _submitButtonText = "Sign Up";
    } else {
      _switchButtonText = "Have an Account? Sign In";
      _newFormState = "signIn";
      _submitButtonText = "Sign Up";
    }

    return [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: primaryColor,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              _submitButtonText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: submit,
        ),
      ),
      showForgotPassword(_showForgotPassword),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          _switchButtonText,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          switchFormState(_newFormState);
        },
      ),

    ];
  }

    List<Widget> buildOre() {
    String _switchButtonText;
    bool _showForgotPassword = false;

    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signIn) {
      _switchButtonText = "Create New Account";

      _showForgotPassword = true;
    } else if (authFormType == AuthFormType.reset) {
      _switchButtonText = "Return to Sign In";

    } else if (authFormType == AuthFormType.convert) {
      _switchButtonText = "Cancel";

    } else {
      _switchButtonText = "Have an Account? Sign In";

    }

    return [
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
        child: RaisedButton(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          color: Colors.white,
          textColor: primaryColor,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(
              ''

            ),
          ),
          onPressed: submit,
        ),
      ),
      showForgotPassword(_showForgotPassword),
      FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          _switchButtonText,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () {

        },
      ),

    ];
  }

  Widget showForgotPassword(bool visible) {
    return Visibility(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          "Forgot Password?",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            authFormType = AuthFormType.reset;
          });
        },
      ),
      visible: visible,
    );
  }





}
```

[THIS IS THE FIREBASE-FIRESTORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdNJe.png)

[THIS IS THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py6NW.png)

Comment: Do you have a ```DoctorHome``` screen? Also, do you have any way to differentiate if a user is a client or a doctor?

Comment: There are two Homescreens the doctor's home screen and the client's home screen. In firestore each user has a role. So the client has a role set to the user while the doctor has a role set to the doctor. I just need to have each appropriate user to get directed to their specific homepage. I'm trying to use shared preferences to save the detail(role) locally and use that to determine to go to the doctor's page or the client's page. Or alternatively, fetch the roles from firestore and determine if the user is a doctor or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `DoctorsHome` is the name of your screen and that `isDoctor` is the field indicating if the role of the user is 'doctor'.

This way, if the user is signed you are going to show either DoctorHome or UsersHome based on isDoctor, and OnboardingScreen otherwise.

**EDIT**

```dart
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
        final String role = snapshot.data['role'];
        final bool isDoctor;
        if (role=='doctor') { isDoctor = true } else { isDoctor = false}
        return signedIn ? (){ isDoctor ? DoctorsHome() : UsersHome() }() : OnboardingScreen();
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a field indicating if the role of the user is 'doctor'.

Comment: how do you identify in your Firebase/cloud db or in your snapshot if a user is doctor/user?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of my firestore dB also the code when i put itcheck tthe top for it

Comment: In any case, I recommend you to place a toggle breakpoint on your ```final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData``` and see what info has your snapshot. This way you will be able to reference your 'role' info

Comment: It gives the error on final String role = snapshot.data['role'];that
"The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.dartargument_type_not_assignable" after removing final

Comment: Since we will be fetching data from firestore I don't think to modify the home controller will work try having a separate class that handles fetching the firestore data.                                                                                                             Then the last choice is then to use shared preferences.